# xls export problemusing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there any way or example to export xls on rails 2.3.5 without using gems and something complicated?

I'm trying to export to xls with conditions by ejectuve_id that i selected
i have this code

```
 *********It s in my controller********  
      @search_ejecutive = params[:search_ejecutive].to_i
      @search_status = params[:status_id].to_i
      @list_ejecutives_comision = Ejecutive.find(:all)
      ejecutive_ids = []

      obj_user.ejecutives.each do |ejecutive|
        @list_ejecutives_comision << Ejecutive.find(ejecutive.id)
      end

      @list_policies_search = Policy.deleted_is(0)

      if params[:search_ejecutive].to_i!=0
        @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.ejecutive_id_is(@search_ejecutive)
      end

      ejecutive_ids = []
      obj_user.ejecutives.each do |ejecutive|
         ejecutive_ids << ejecutive.id
      end

      if !ejecutive_ids.blank?
          @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.ejecutive_id_in(ejecutive_ids)
      end 

     @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.deleted_is(0)
     @list_policies = @list_policies_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

And here i'm showing links that i tried

```
    <% form_remote_tag :url=>{:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial"},:before=>"load_close('loading_search')",:success=>"load_off('loading_search')" do -%>


    <label>Ejecutivo:</label>
    <%= select_tag 'search_ejecutive',"<option value=\"\">Seleccione</option>"+options_for_select(@list_ejecutives_comision.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]})%>

   <input name="Buscar" value="Buscar" type="submit" /><span id="loading_search"></span>
<% end %>
  <%= link_to("xls","http://localhost:3000/policy_management/policy/generate_print_ejecutive/generate_print_ejecutive.xls")%>

  <%= link_to "xls", :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive",:format=>"xls" ,:search => params[:search_ejecutive],:page => params[:page]    %>

  <%= link_to 'Imprimir', :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive", :format=>"pdf" %>
   <div id="table">
<%= render :partial=>"table2" %>
```

My :partial table2 is the result of @list_policies
My teacher doesn't want doesn't want to reveal me the secret ,told me that the trick is

```
@list_policies
```

I tried to export manually and i tried this

```
@list_policies.find(:all,:conditions=>"ejecutive id = 1")
```

Somebody can help me with this, my teache told me that i need to export :search_ejecutive params

I will appreciate all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way by which newest format of xls can be represented by an xml, you can read more about it [here](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML).

So your controller can answer `.xls` requests, and you can then have a view `generate_print_executive.xls.erb` like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
          xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
          xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
          xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
          xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <% @list_policies.each do |policy| %>
        <Row>
          <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String"><%= policy.column_data %></Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
      <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Notice this is just a dummy example on how to generate a `.xls` without using any gem, I wasn't able to understand what you need on your post, I'm mostly answering the title of the post :P